# Using TLP with a Docking Station - Docking Station not charging thinkpad

Tags: power-management, thinkpad, dock-station

I am using a Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th Gen with a USB-C Gen 2 Docking Station. When I am not using TLP the docking station is charging my Thinkpad just fine. Also all peripherals work as expected. As soon as I enable TLP and unplug and replug the thunderbolt 3 cable, it won't charge anymore. Though the Thinkpad is still receiving power, because it does not use any power (0.0W) and it all peripherals still work as expected.

So I guess it must be a TLP setting, or deeper on kernel level. But I am not able to figure this out on my own.

I am using the latest mainline kernel version 5.5.7 on Pop_os

```
5.5.7-050507-generic
Pop!_OS 19.10 x86_64
```

dmesg gives me the following output for unplugging and replugging the docking station:

```
[ 233.834081] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 10
[ 233.834089] usb 1-3.3: USB disconnect, device number 11
[ 233.834094] usb 1-3.3.3: USB disconnect, device number 12
[ 233.834098] usb 1-3.3.3.1: USB disconnect, device number 16
[ 233.835727] usb 1-3.3.3.2: USB disconnect, device number 14
[ 233.968761] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: remove, state 1
[ 233.968764] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[ 233.968943] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[ 233.968948] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: remove, state 4
[ 233.968949] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[ 233.969045] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[ 233.969048] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
[ 233.969107] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[ 233.989380] usb 1-3.3.3.4: USB disconnect, device number 15
[ 234.222560] pci_bus 0000:06: Allocating resources
[ 234.222592] pcieport 0000:06:01.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] to [bus 08-3a] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 234.222599] pcieport 0000:06:04.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] to [bus 3c-6f] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 234.222611] pcieport 0000:06:01.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 234.222614] pcieport 0000:06:01.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 234.222618] pcieport 0000:06:04.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 234.222621] pcieport 0000:06:04.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 234.222625] pcieport 0000:06:04.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 234.222628] pcieport 0000:06:04.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 234.222631] pcieport 0000:06:01.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 234.222634] pcieport 0000:06:01.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 239.042638] pcieport 0000:06:02.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 239.043109] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[ 239.043457] pci_bus 0000:07: busn_res: [bus 07] is released
[ 239.043615] pci_bus 0000:08: busn_res: [bus 08-3a] is released
[ 239.043744] pci_bus 0000:3b: busn_res: [bus 3b] is released
[ 239.044263] pci_bus 0000:3c: busn_res: [bus 3c-6f] is released
[ 239.044511] pci_bus 0000:06: busn_res: [bus 06-6f] is released
[ 240.980458] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 241.011323] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=a392, bcdDevice= c.d4
[ 241.011326] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 241.011328] usb 1-3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 241.011329] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[ 241.013185] hub 1-3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 241.013380] hub 1-3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 241.736745] usb 1-3.3: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 241.760620] usb 1-3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=a394, bcdDevice= c.d3
[ 241.760626] usb 1-3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 241.760630] usb 1-3.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 241.760633] usb 1-3.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[ 241.762403] hub 1-3.3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 241.762719] hub 1-3.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 242.472411] usb 1-3.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 242.508814] usb 1-3.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=a395, bcdDevice=60.70
[ 242.508820] usb 1-3.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=0
[ 242.508824] usb 1-3.3.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 242.508827] usb 1-3.3.3: Manufacturer: Lenovo
[ 242.510349] hub 1-3.3.3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 242.510740] hub 1-3.3.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 242.804447] usb 1-3.3.3.1: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[ 242.912015] usb 1-3.3.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=a38f, bcdDevice= 0.00
[ 242.912021] usb 1-3.3.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 242.912025] usb 1-3.3.3.1: Product: Billboard Device
[ 242.912029] usb 1-3.3.3.1: Manufacturer: Cypress Semiconductor
[ 242.912031] usb 1-3.3.3.1: SerialNumber: 0001
[ 242.919200] hid-generic 0003:17EF:A38F.0009: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Cypress Semiconductor Billboard Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.3.3.1/input1
[ 243.000482] usb 1-3.3.3.2: new full-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 243.292137] usb 1-3.3.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=a396, bcdDevice= 0.07
[ 243.292144] usb 1-3.3.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 243.292148] usb 1-3.3.3.2: Product: ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen2 USB Audio
[ 243.292151] usb 1-3.3.3.2: Manufacturer: Lenovo
[ 243.292153] usb 1-3.3.3.2: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[ 243.434979] input: Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen2 USB Audio as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.3/1-3.3.3/1-3.3.3.2/1-3.3.3.2:1.3/0003:17EF:A396.000A/input/input20
[ 243.492972] hid-generic 0003:17EF:A396.000A: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen2 USB Audio] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.3.3.2/input3
[ 243.576566] usb 1-3.3.3.4: new low-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[ 243.685959] usb 1-3.3.3.4: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c069, bcdDevice=56.01
[ 243.685964] usb 1-3.3.3.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 243.685967] usb 1-3.3.3.4: Product: USB Laser Mouse
[ 243.685970] usb 1-3.3.3.4: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 243.695114] input: Logitech USB Laser Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.3/1-3.3.3/1-3.3.3.4/1-3.3.3.4:1.0/0003:046D:C069.000B/input/input21
[ 243.695728] hid-generic 0003:046D:C069.000B: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Laser Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3.3.3.4/input0
[ 246.381985] thinkpad_acpi: undocked from hotplug port replicator
[ 249.321042] pci 0000:05:00.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 249.321101] pci 0000:05:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[ 249.321189] pci 0000:05:00.0: supports D1 D2
[ 249.321190] pci 0000:05:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 249.321446] pci 0000:06:00.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 249.321508] pci 0000:06:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[ 249.321595] pci 0000:06:00.0: supports D1 D2
[ 249.321596] pci 0000:06:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 249.321699] pci 0000:06:01.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 249.321761] pci 0000:06:01.0: enabling Extended Tags
[ 249.321841] pci 0000:06:01.0: supports D1 D2
[ 249.321841] pci 0000:06:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 249.321938] pci 0000:06:02.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 249.322001] pci 0000:06:02.0: enabling Extended Tags
[ 249.322081] pci 0000:06:02.0: supports D1 D2
[ 249.322082] pci 0000:06:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 249.322200] pci 0000:06:04.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[ 249.322261] pci 0000:06:04.0: enabling Extended Tags
[ 249.322341] pci 0000:06:04.0: supports D1 D2
[ 249.322342] pci 0000:06:04.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 249.322457] pci 0000:05:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 06-6f]
[ 249.322465] pci 0000:05:00.0: bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xe01fffff]
[ 249.322470] pci 0000:05:00.0: bridge window [mem 0x2000000000-0x20005fffff 64bit pref]
[ 249.322510] pci 0000:06:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 07]
[ 249.322518] pci 0000:06:00.0: bridge window [mem 0xe0100000-0xe01fffff]
[ 249.322565] pci 0000:06:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 08-3a]
[ 249.322643] pci 0000:3b:00.0: [8086:15d4] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[ 249.322677] pci 0000:3b:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xe0000000-0xe000ffff]
[ 249.322755] pci 0000:3b:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[ 249.322866] pci 0000:3b:00.0: supports D1 D2
[ 249.322867] pci 0000:3b:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[ 249.322954] pci 0000:3b:00.0: 8.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s x4 link at 0000:06:02.0 (capable of 31.504 Gb/s with 8 GT/s x4 link)
[ 249.323105] pci 0000:06:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3b]
[ 249.323114] pci 0000:06:02.0: bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xe00fffff]
[ 249.323173] pci 0000:06:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3c-6f]
[ 249.323213] pci_bus 0000:06: Allocating resources
[ 249.323232] pci 0000:06:01.0: bridge window [io 0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 08-3a] add_size 1000
[ 249.323234] pci 0000:06:01.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 08-3a] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 249.323236] pci 0000:06:01.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] to [bus 08-3a] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 249.323238] pci 0000:06:02.0: bridge window [io 0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3b] add_size 1000
[ 249.323240] pci 0000:06:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 3b] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 249.323242] pci 0000:06:04.0: bridge window [io 0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3c-6f] add_size 1000
[ 249.323244] pci 0000:06:04.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 3c-6f] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 249.323246] pci 0000:06:04.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff] to [bus 3c-6f] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[ 249.323248] pci 0000:05:00.0: bridge window [io 0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 06-6f] add_size 4000
[ 249.323251] pci 0000:05:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x4000]
[ 249.323252] pci 0000:05:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x4000]
[ 249.323254] pci 0000:05:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x4000]
[ 249.323255] pci 0000:05:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x4000]
[ 249.323259] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 249.323260] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 249.323263] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x2000000000-0x20001fffff 64bit pref]
[ 249.323264] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x2000200000-0x20003fffff 64bit pref]
[ 249.323266] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 249.323267] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 249.323269] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 15: assigned [mem 0x2000400000-0x20005fffff 64bit pref]
[ 249.323270] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323272] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323273] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323274] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323276] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323277] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323280] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 249.323281] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 249.323282] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323284] pci 0000:06:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323285] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323286] pci 0000:06:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323288] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 14: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 249.323289] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[ 249.323290] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323291] pci 0000:06:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io size 0x1000]
[ 249.323293] pci 0000:06:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 07]
[ 249.323299] pci 0000:06:00.0: bridge window [mem 0xe0100000-0xe01fffff]
[ 249.323307] pci 0000:06:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 08-3a]
[ 249.323314] pci 0000:06:01.0: bridge window [mem 0x2000000000-0x20001fffff 64bit pref]
[ 249.323320] pci 0000:06:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3b]
[ 249.323325] pci 0000:06:02.0: bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xe00fffff]
[ 249.323328] pci 0000:06:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x2000200000-0x20003fffff 64bit pref]
[ 249.323334] pci 0000:06:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3c-6f]
[ 249.323341] pci 0000:06:04.0: bridge window [mem 0x2000400000-0x20005fffff 64bit pref]
[ 249.323347] pci 0000:05:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 06-6f]
[ 249.323351] pci 0000:05:00.0: bridge window [mem 0xe0000000-0xe01fffff]
[ 249.323355] pci 0000:05:00.0: bridge window [mem 0x2000000000-0x20005fffff 64bit pref]
[ 249.324692] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[ 249.324698] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[ 249.325818] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000200009810
[ 249.326019] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.05
[ 249.326020] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[ 249.326021] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[ 249.326022] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.5.7-050507-generic xhci-hcd
[ 249.326023] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:3b:00.0
[ 249.327844] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 249.327855] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[ 249.328399] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[ 249.328402] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[ 249.328404] xhci_hcd 0000:3b:00.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[ 249.328429] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.05
[ 249.328430] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[ 249.328431] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[ 249.328432] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.5.7-050507-generic xhci-hcd
[ 249.328433] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:3b:00.0
[ 249.328527] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[ 249.328535] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[ 249.773289] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeedPlus Gen 2 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 249.796319] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=a391, bcdDevice= c.d4
[ 249.796329] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 249.796334] usb 4-1: Product: USB3.1 Hub
[ 249.796340] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[ 249.800011] hub 4-1:1.0: USB hub found
[ 249.800362] hub 4-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 250.360884] usb 4-1.1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 250.381464] usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=a387, bcdDevice=31.03
[ 250.381471] usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[ 250.381475] usb 4-1.1: Product: USB-C Dock Ethernet
[ 250.381478] usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 250.381482] usb 4-1.1: SerialNumber: 301000001
[ 250.464633] usb 4-1.3: new SuperSpeedPlus Gen 2 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 250.488625] usb 4-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=a393, bcdDevice= c.d3
[ 250.488626] usb 4-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 250.488628] usb 4-1.3: Product: USB3.1 Hub
[ 250.488628] usb 4-1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[ 250.492688] hub 4-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[ 250.492928] hub 4-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 250.565073] usb 4-1.1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 250.588770] r8152 4-1.1:1.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8153b-2.fw failed with error -2
[ 250.588778] r8152 4-1.1:1.0: unable to load firmware patch rtl_nic/rtl8153b-2.fw (-2)
[ 250.621675] r8152 4-1.1:1.0 eth0: v1.11.11
[ 251.242748] r8152 4-1.1:1.0 enx482ae33f6fa5: renamed from eth0
[ 252.211769] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx482ae33f6fa5: link becomes ready
[ 252.212526] r8152 4-1.1:1.0 enx482ae33f6fa5: carrier on
```